# If I buy a banana at the market, is there any chance that an insect is hiding inside it?

Tags: entomology, food, fruit, arachnology

I watched this horrifying video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d54PyNN1EdU). It shows movement beneath the skin of a banana and then a spider pushes it's way out.

Suffice to say I'm too scared to eat bananas anymore!

I would like to know what is the probability that an insect is hiding inside a banana that I buy at the market? Even if there was just one chance in a million that an insect is hiding inside I would stop eating bananas forever.

I postulate that an insect could lay it's eggs in a banana and then the offsprings would be born inside the banana. Or perhaps an insect tries to eat a small chunk of the banana, it cuts his way out inside the banana, it gets trapped inside, and then someone buys the banana. Both of these ideas are troublesome since I'm not sure if there is air to breathe inside the banana.

Comment: The thing that comes out of the banana in the video is not an insect. Where do you plan buying a banana (where do you live?)? In a Wall-Mart at Fairbanks, Alaska or at a local market at Jakarta?

Comment: That video could be fake.

Comment: If you're scared of insects and insect eggs being in your food you're about to go VERY hungry. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Food_Defect_Action_Levels

Comment: I like the question, but I think the reason you're getting so many down votes (and why I down voted) is because you link to a spider and ask about insects. Remember they are different and this is a pet peeve of entomologists! Did you actually mean to ask about insects, spiders, or anything in between?

Comment: That's not why I voted - I voted because I feel it's not on topic and primarily opinion based, and I've spent the last 7 years working with insects :)

Answer (score 7):

[Kaleb Lechowski](http://kaleblechowski.tumblr.com), creator of that video, is a digital creator and animator of critters. I would propose that he did a very good job of rendering a CGI spider to burst from a banana.

Spiders (which are not insects remember) won't eat bananas. In fact, only one species is known to be mostly herbivorous: [*Bagheera kiplingi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagheera_kiplingi).

However, don't eat that banana just yet! The internet is littered with tales of horror about spiders in fruit. Like this [Black Widow](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/earth/wildlife/11650715/Black-widow-spider-found-in-grapes-from-Asda-in-Leamington-Spa.html) in a bunch of grapes. There is no bursting out of the fruit like Alien, but what has happened is the spider has unwittingly found itself being picked from its natural environment and transported with the fruit.

**Fruit is good.** Stay sceptical of internet rumours that are trying to get clicks with fear, and stay measured enough to remember that the benefits of eating (washed, clean) fruit far outweigh the extraordinarily low chance of finding a nasty bug hiding away.

Comment: Also I'd suggest many/most insects/spiders are edible, so there's no reason to be scared